# Not able to display the data in Kony Charts

Tags: javascript, json, xml, soap

-> We want to display the data in our charts in Kony Studio which we are getting from SOAP services.

->We had used "appmiddlewaresecureinvokerasync” method by following way:

if(IS_SECURE){

getH1ChartDataNew = appmiddlewaresecureinvokerasync(getH1ChartData_inputparam, callback);

}

else

{

getH1ChartDataNew = appmiddlewareinvokerasync(getH1ChartData_inputparam, callback);

}

->After that we started tomcat server and published the services and they are published successfully.

-> We added 3 system calls "opstatus", "errcode", "errmsg" and from that we are getting status 0 which means we are getting success in service. But still we are not able to get the data.

-> we are using this function:

function callback(status, result) 
{

alert("OPSTATUS"+result.opstatus);

alert("ERRCODE"+result.errcode);

alert("ERRMSG"+result.errmsg);

if (status == 400)

{

alert(result["HistoryKey"]);

if(result["HistoryKey"]!=null)

{

} 
};

var getH1ChartData_inputparam = {} 
getH1ChartData_inputparam["serviceID"] =   "GetHistoryTrend15DaysGrossOutPutInfo";

getH1ChartData_inputparam["token"] = token;

getH1ChartData_inputparam["httpheaders"] = {};

getH1ChartData_inputparam["httpconfig"] = {};

if(IS_SECURE){ 
getH1ChartDataNew = appmiddlewaresecureinvokerasync(getH1ChartData_inputparam, callback);

}

else

{

getH1ChartDataNew = appmiddlewareinvokerasync(getH1ChartData_inputparam, callback);

}

-> We are using kony version 6.5 and ios simulator 9.1.

Please provide the resolution for this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, You need to check your kony setting.